# Why its goof practise to write new unit-test for every change?

Tags: unit-testing

If we want to test a function.
Why is it a good practise to write new unit-tests rather then add to current one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unit test should be as readable as possible. Therefore it's a good practice to only test one single thing with one unit test. This comes also with the benefit, that you know immediately which function has a problem, if one of your tests fails.

Example: You test functionA and functionB in one unit test. If the test fails, it's not clear whether there is an error in functionA or functionB.
But if you create one unit test per function and one of them fails, you know immediately which function contains the problem.

Comment: what about test code duplication?
And additional test startup time

Comment: Since tests are not productive code, code duplication is not that much of a problem. There are also ways to minimize code duplication by using methods that are shared between tests. However I usually prefer having some duplication for the sake of readability. The startup time of tests should not be an issue.